# Is this Polymorphism and is this bad practice?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I'm setting up a State system for my game.

```
class State
{
protected:
 enum State_
 {
     STATE_INTRO,
     STATE_GAME,
     STATE_PAUSE,
     STATE_CUTSCENE,
 };
public:
 State();
 virtual void run(State_) = 0;
 virtual ~State(); // virtual destructor cus we will be inheriting this class
};
```

I then have inherited classes which represent each state

```
class IntroState : public State
{

public:
    void run(State_ STATE);
};
```

I want the `run` function to have different functionality based off of what state the game is in, is it bad practice to achieve that like this:

```
void IntroState::run(State_ STATE)
{
    if (STATE == STATE_INTRO)
    {
        // load the intro
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how else to do this, thanks (and keep in my mind I'm JUST learning about states so I might be completely off here)

Comment: Correct ne if i'm wrong, but are you planning to inherit from `State` for every case? Like `IntroState`, `GameState`, etc.? Because if so, you can achieve different functionality simply by changing what the `run` function does, without needing to check `STATE`.

Comment: Oh crap I think I see what you're saying, yes I do want to inherit from State for each state, so would you recommend I just create an object of each state and then when I need to run a specific function, I just call that objects run command?

Comment: By the way, `virtual ~State() = default;` is a nice way of introducing the virtual destructor because then you don't need to write the definition yourself.

Comment: @BobbyT432 Yep. The part of your code that will call the `run` function will be aware of `STATE` (otherwise it couldn't pass it as an argument) so it should be able to select the right instance of `run` to call.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks I'll do that! @melk okay but would this be considered polymorphism? Cus instead of passing in an enum to change the state, I'll have to call that specifics state run command right? Like ```IntroState.run()``` instead of ```State.run(ENUM WHICH TELLS WHAT RUN TO USE)```, I'm not sure if I explained that very well but do you see what I'm trying to say?

Comment: @BobbyT432 That depends on how your organise things. I did something similar where I had the `State` class call a function in a `Game` class to set the index of the next `State` (also using enums). The `Game` class would then index into a `vector<std::unique_ptr<State>>` with that `enum`, choosing the right one and running it. Don't know if there are better ways to do it, but it definitely uses polymorphism ;)

Comment: @BobbyT432 That's sort of the point of polymorphism.. to call method 'x' and get behavior for the *specific* run-time object. (Then one has to choose the correct run-time object to call the method on; it's flipping the issue 90 degrees.)

Comment: @melk Thank you, I think I get an idea of it now.

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah I'm just learning polymorphism and using it so I have mixed definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here is a possible approach (improvements are appreciated):

```
class Game {
  //... Initialize all State-derived classes in constructor and put them in states (not shown)
  vector<unique_ptr>> states;
  State_ currentState {STATE_INTRO};
  State_ nextState {STATE_INTRO};
  public:
    void setNextState(State_ state ) {nextState = state;}
    void Play() { 
      for(;;) { //endless loop
        if (!states[currentState]->run()) return;//stopping when run returns false
        currentState = nextState;
      }
    }
};
```

And `run` could look like this:

```
class IntroState : public State {
  //... 
  void run(Game& game) {
    // do stuff
    game.setNextState(STATE_GAME);
    return true;
  }
};
```

Of course, you need to figure out the include order, and you'll need to forward-declare `Game` in `State.hpp` (the code shown here only shows the central idea). Also, the implementations of `run` and `Play` should of course be in seperate .cpp files (didn't do that here so this example wouldn't get too long)

Comment: This helps alot! Is State_ in your case an enum a class or what type is that?

Comment: @BobbyT432 It's the same `enum` you use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need polymorphism in your case since you will only have one `State` class in your application (correct me if I'm wrong).

You're run function would look like this:

```cpp
void run(State_ state)
{
  switch (state)
  {
    case STATE_INTRO:
      doIntro();
    case STATE_BLAH:
      doBlah();
    // fill all you states...
  }
}

void doIntro()
{
  // do something for the intro
}

void doBlah()
{
  // do something for blah
}
```

Now if you really wanna get fancy and remove the `switch` statement:

```cpp
class State
{
    private:
        void doA() {}
        void doB() {}

        enum State_
        {
            A = 0,
            B,
            END_
        };

        std::function<void(void)> functions[END_];

    public:
        State()
        {
            functions[A] = std::bind(&State::doA, this);
            functions[B] = std::bind(&State::doB, this);
        }

        void run(State_ state)
        {
            functions[state]();
        }
};
```

Comment: Hmm, okay I see what you're saying, however I was originally planning on creating multiple class instances of ```State``` which would be like "```IntroState``` ```PauseState```, etc, and then I wanted to be able to potentially store each one of them in a pointer object of ```State```, then maybe do it like this ```State->run(INTRO_STATE)```, know what I'm trying to say? I don't know if this is entirely practical but that was my end goal

Comment: You mean you wanted to specify the implementation of `IntroState` into a child class of `State`? Or do you mean that you will have multiple `IntroState` in you application?

Comment: I wanted to specify the implementation of ```IntroState``` into a child class of ```State```

Comment: I think in your case you don't really need inheritance as your `State` class has only one `IntroState`. It will be easier for you to manage a single class rather than multiple inherited class. For example how will you remember which State is what in your array of `State`? You would have to put arithmetic in place to handle that.

Comment: Even if I expand and add like 10 inherited ```State```s? So you're saying just delegate one class to every single state in the game?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your project I guess. If for one `State_` you will have only one implementation then I would stick with a single class that calls the right methods for that `State_`. If you need to implement different behaviors for one `State_` then you should use inheritance.